# Add a custom made component to a datagridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to add a custom built component to a column in datagridview. As far as I know, I can add buttons textboxes using the code below:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn buttons = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
{
    buttons.HeaderText = "Move Up";
    buttons.Text = "⇧";
    buttons.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
    buttons.AutoSizeMode =
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    buttons.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    buttons.CellTemplate.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    buttons.DisplayIndex = 3;
    buttons.Width = 60;
}
```

Is there any way that I can add a custom built component to a column?

Comment: You have to derive a class from `DataGridViewColumn` and implement your own custom component column class.

Comment: Note that a) there is a full example on msdn and b) it is quite some work to even add the necessary dummy event etc..